# Clarification on definition of differentiability of vector-valued functions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definition

As it is normally stated, the definition of differentiability of vector-valued function is as follows:

$\textbf{Definition:}$ Let $U \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ be open, and let $a \in U$. A vector-valued function $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if there is a linear map $Df(a): \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$ so that
$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-Df(a)h}{\Vert h \Vert} = 0.$$

My question is, is the vector $h$ implicitly assumed to be arbitrary such that it is analogous for the case of real-valued functions where the direction of approaching the limit point should not matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $h$ is whatever vector of any direction in the definition of differentiability. You just have obviously to have $a+h \in U$.

Comment: Other definitions I have read made no mention of an open set $U$. Does this mean that open sets are not crucial to the definition?

Comment: @TheLastCipher The definition of "differentiable" you have given in the question seems to be missing something in that it sets up $U$ and then doesn't do anything with it. Did you skip a part saying that $U$ is a subset of the domain of $f$? It's common (though perhaps not universal) to assume there is an open set/disk around $a$ in the domain, so that you can approach $a$ in all ways, as the answer here mentions.

Comment: @MarkS. No, I did not skip anything. Though the way you put it made me understand the significance of that open set $U$. Thanks!